# Exiting While loop before time

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, return-value

I am trying to do, it is that while exits when file_name = 'q' not when it returns the value of file_name.

```
#/usr/bin/env python3

def say_hola():
    print("Hola, Mundo!")


def dir_file_name():
    active = True
    while active:
        file_name = input("Enter WO # or 'q' to QUIT: ")
        if file_name.lower() == 'q':
            active = False
        elif file_name == '':
            print("Wrong entry -*-BLANKS-*- are not allowed...")
            continue
        else:
            say_hola()
            return file_name

dir_name = dir_file_name()
print(f"\n\n\t{dir_name}\n")
```

Comment: Instead of `active = False` just use `break`.

Comment: `return` exits the entire function, including the loop. If you don't want to leave the loop, you can't use `return`.